# tratando de realizar un overlay sobre una imagen

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de crear un efecto overlay de abajo arriba para una imagen al hacer hover sobre esta y que muestre un texto centrado, pero no lo consigo. Me he informado mucho, he visto muchos tutoriales, pero no lo consigo aplicar, ya que me contenedor de imágenes es flex y necesito crear este efecto. Agradezco toda ayuda. Adjunto mi código html y css

```css
.containerFotos{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.containerFotos img{
    margin-top: -150px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.comida{
    position: absolute;
    left: 7.9%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 34.2%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 184%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.comida:hover .overlay{
   background-color: yellow;
   /*height: 100px;*/
}

.overlay{
    transition: height 10s;
    background-color:rgba(43, 34, 68, 0.9);
}

.overlay:hover{
    height: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerFotos">
  <img src="../img/descarga.jpg" />

     <div class="comida">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p> prueba </p>
         </div> 
     </div>   
   
  
  <img src="../img/MATUMBO-STEW-800x510.jpg"/>
  <img src="../img/IMG_20170817_151825_mini-1024x576.jpg"/>
  <img src="../img/150304102311-irio-cnn-super-169-1024x576.jpg"/>
  <img  src="../img/maharagwe-poa-pinterest-1024x538.jpg"/>
  <img src="../img/tanzaniasafariprivatetours_wali-wa-nazi_riso-al-cocco-1024x629.jpg"/>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto sea lo que necesites.

La estructura de cada tarjeta es esta:

```
      <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
           <div class="overlay">
                <p>prueba </p>
            </div>  
      </div>
```

Donde primero viene la imagen y después el "overlay" Tanto la imagen como el overlay tienen `position:absolute;` para que se sobrepongan en el momento en qual `top:0; left:0;`. También quiero que el div `.comida` tenga `overflow: hidden;`: lo que sobresale no se ve.

Al cargarse la pagina el `overlay` tiene top:100% y queda completamente fuera del contenedor `.comida`

Al pasar con el ratón por encima del contenedor `.comida` el `.overlay` pasa a tener `top:0`, y para que el cambio no sea brusco le puse `transition:top 1s;`

```css
.containerFotos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

.comida {
  width: 130px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:1em;
}

img,
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 150, 0.3);
  top:100%;
  transition:top 1s;
}

.comida:hover .overlay{
  top:0%;
}
.overlay p {
  text-align: center; 
  line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerFotos">

   <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>prueba </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
     <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>prueba </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
     <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>prueba </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
     <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>prueba </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
     <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>prueba </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
     <div class="comida">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg"/>
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>prueba </p>
         </div> 
    </div>


</div>
```

#### Actualización

Después de varios comentarios y después de ver en codepen un ejemplo funcional he llegado a esta versión:

```css
.containerFotos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.comida {
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 150, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 85%;
  /*transform: translate(-50px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-350px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-350px); 
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-350px);*/

  transition: 1s;
}

.comida:hover .overlay {
  top: 0%;
}

.overlay p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerFotos">

      <div class="comida">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x400.jpg" />
         <div class="overlay">
           <p> prueba </p>
          </div> 
      </div>   
   
   <div class="comida">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x510.jpg"/>
    <div class="overlay">
           <p> prueba </p>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="comida">    
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x576.jpg"/>
    <div class="overlay">
           <p> prueba </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="comida">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x576.jpg"/>
    <div class="overlay">
           <p> prueba </p>
          </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="comida">    
    <img  src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x538.jpg"/>
    <div class="overlay">
           <p> prueba </p>
          </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="comida">   
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x629.jpg"/>
    <div class="overlay">
           <p> prueba </p>
          </div>
      </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Es justo lo que quiero, pero se me desestructura toda la página, añado imagen como respuesta.

Comment: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibCY1.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibCY1.gif) como se puede ver en la imagen, ya no ha respetado en contenedor flex, el texto se ha ido de sitio y demás

Comment: esto pasa porque tus imágenes son muy grandes mientras que las mias son pequeñas. Si tus imágenes son tan grandes porque necesitas utilizar `display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;`?

Comment: porque las quiero en columnas, dos columnas y cuando cambie de resolución pues hagan el salto

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia pero no veo cual es la actualización. A parte, he encontrado donde vaya y se rompe la web. es en el bloque img, .overlay{ position: absolute} si se le pone esa propiedad, la web entera se rompe. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: El `.overlay`, tiene que estar encima de la imagen. Para que esto pase tienes que darle `position:absolute` y al contenedor .comida` tienes que darle  `position: relative;` para que la `position:absolute` del  `.overlay` sea relativo al contenedor .comida`. Por favor crea un codepen con una versión simplificada de lo que tienes

Comment: https://codepen.io/scorpions/pen/GaNbZV lo que quiero es como está, pero que el div, crezca hacia arriba tapando toda la imagen y el texto se quede en medio. Pero ocurre un problema y es el que he pasado en la imagen de abajo

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta con lo que he visto en codepen. Sin embargo hay una cosa que no me gusta: las imágenes tienen varios tamaños y no tienen el mismo raport altura - anchura. En tu código tienes el div .comida a 400px y después tienes `img {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}` Esto quiere decir que las imágenes aparecerán deformadas. Esto es lo que haría: en lugar de utilizar imágenes utilizaría `background-image` para el div `.comida` y `background-size:cover;`

Comment: Mil gracias @enxanta oajalá llegue a los niveles de conocimiento que hay en esta grandísima web, ayudáis a muchísima gente!!!! Gracias de nuevo compañero